# How to use JPA-Entities as a dependency with maven

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, jpa

I got in a multimodule-maven-project an entities project in which there are some Entity and DAO classes. Also there are some integration-tests which I'd like to seperate in an own project called entities-IT.
Now I've put the entities-project as an dependency to the entites-IT-project but if I run the build there occurs an error message like this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project entities-IT: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /some/path/to/project/entities-IT/src/it/java/com/example/persistence/dao/ExampleDaoIT.java:[25,38] cannot access com.example.persistence.ExampleEntity
[ERROR]   bad class file: /some/path/to/project/persistence/ExampleEntity.class
[ERROR]     illegal start of class file
[ERROR]     Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the classpath.
```

This is strange because in the target folder there are all of mentioned .class files and the folderstructure is also correct.

Is there anything to take notice if using Entities as a dependency in another project?

In the `pom.xml` of the entities-project there is some code-generation going on:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <configuration>
            <source>1.8</source>
            <target>1.8</target>
            <compilerArguments>
                        <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
            </compilerArguments>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>process</id>
                <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/metamodel</outputDirectory>
                <compilerArguments>
                    -Aeclipselink.persistencexml=${project.basedir}/src/main/java/META-INF/persistence.xml
                </compilerArguments>
                <processors>
<processor>org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.modelgen.CanonicalModelProcessor
                    </processor>
                </processors>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
...
</build>
```

and then I have the dependency set in the entities-IT-project:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>example</groupId>
     <artifactId>entities</artifactId>
     <version>${parent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

and run the tests with the failsafe-plugin:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0</version>
     <executions>
          <execution>
               <id>add-integration-test-sources</id>
               <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
               <goals>
                    <goal>add-test-source</goal>
               </goals>
               <configuration>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/it/java</source>
                    </sources>
               </configuration>
           </execution>
           <execution>
                    <id>add-integration-test-resources</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-resource</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                         <resources>
                              <resource>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                                <directory>src/it/resources</directory>
                              </resource>
                         </resources>
                    </configuration>
           </execution>
      </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
     <executions>
          <execution>
               <id>integration-test</id>
               <goals>
                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    <goal>verify</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
     </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Please include your pom.xml of entites-IT-project

Comment: I have added some Content of the pom-files. I hope it will help. If you need more information let me know